# Can we customize buttons of UIAlertviewController in swift?

Tags: swift, uialertview

I am trying to customize buttons of UIAlertView but however I am unable to achieve it, I am new to swift and I don't how to achieve.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no you can not customise default `alertViewController` buttons but you can achieve it by using custom `alertView`.

[HERE](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=custom%20alertview&ref=simplesearch&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) is some available libraries you can use.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but now my question is cant we do without using any libraries?

Comment: As I said in my answer **no you can not**.:)

Answer (score 0):

To followup on @Dharmesh Kheni's answer, while you get no additional functionality for UIAlertViewController in swift, you can still use libraries in your swift code.

I work for Urban Outfitters and we have an open source customizable alert, [URBNAlert](https://github.com/urbn/URBNAlert)

Here is some code, using URBNAlert in swift

```
        let alert = URBNAlertViewController(title: "My Title", message: "Message")

        alert.alertStyler.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        alert.alertStyler.buttonHeight = 44
        alert.alertStyler.buttonTitleColor = UIColor.redColor()
        alert.alertStyler.cancelButtonBackgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        // many, many more things you can customize.

        alert.addAction(URBNAlertAction(title: "Button Title", actionType: .Normal, actionCompleted: { (action) -> Void in
            // do some stuff here when the user selects this button
        }))

        alert.show()
```